# Map function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

```
full['Name'].head(10)
```

here is a Series which show like below:

```
0         Mr
1        Mrs
2       Miss
3        Mrs
4         Mr
5         Mr
6         Mr
7     Master
8        Mrs
9        Mrs
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

And after using the map dict function:

```
full['Name']=full['Name'].map({'Mr':1})
full['Name'].head(100)
```

it turns out to be:

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
6    NaN
7    NaN
8    NaN
9    NaN
10   NaN
11   NaN
12   NaN
13   NaN
14   NaN
15   NaN
16   NaN
17   NaN
18   NaN
19   NaN
20   NaN
21   NaN
22   NaN
23   NaN
24   NaN
25   NaN
26   NaN
27   NaN
28   NaN
29   NaN
```

And it is strange that I have suceed in doing this on the other Series in DataFrame full, which really make me confused.

Please help.

Comment: `map` replaces those values not in the dict's keys with `NaN`. Make sure you don't have leading/trailing spaces, try: `full['Name'].str.strip()`. Also you may want `replace` instead of `map` which doesn't turn non-existing keys with `NaN`.

Comment: the word ,`Mr` hasn't found on throughout the series. As @QuangHoang - suggested apply strip. If you want to keep other values `Master,   Mrs` use `full['Name'].replace({'Mr':1})`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works after adding strip()